# Preserving named ranges when copying XLS using xlutils

Tags: python, xls, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I have some code that opens an Excel workbook with `xlrd`, copies it with `xlutils`, updates it with `xlwt` and then writes it back out to another file.

The resulting workbook is missing all the named ranges that were present in the original.  I'm 100% sure the named ranges are present in the original because I'm actually reading them (from the `xlrd` object, before the copy) and basing my updates on them.

Assuming that this is the natural effect of using `xlutils.copy.copy`, does `xlwt` have some way for me to recreate the named ranges that I read from the `xlrd` version of the same workbook?  The documentation (at least, what I could find) is sparse.

Here is a python session that shows the problem:

```
>>> from xlrd import open_workbook
>>> wb = open_workbook('sc_auction_template.xls', formatting_info=True)
>>> print len(wb.name_obj_list) # see, there are named ranges
9
>>> from xlutils.copy import copy
>>> wb2 = copy(wb)
>>> wb2.save('test.xls')
>>> wb = open_workbook('test.xls')
>>> print len(wb.name_obj_list) # but now there are none!
0
```

Comment: What's "formatting_info=True"? You have put it in the first open, but not the second... Why?

Comment: It's necessary to to xlrd to read the cell formatting information from the spreadsheet.  It's there because I cut this code and edited it down from actual running code.  I don't think it's relevant to the named ranges issue (except that it demonstrates that I had to go to some trouble to even move the cell formats from spreadsheet to spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

For now, the answer is unfortunately **no**, `xlwt` doesn't support writing names.  Maybe someday, but I don't expect it anytime soon.

As far as I know, the only way to programmatically write names in .xls files is to automate a running instance of an application that can, such as Excel itself on Windows with [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) or [`pywinauto`](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) or some flavor of Visual Basic, etc.  I believe there are analogous ways to script OpenOffice.org if Excel is not available to you.